Breakpoint of DNN source code not hitting
I've got the source code of DNN 09.13.04 now I'm trying to debug DNN and want to debug the part where HTML editor stores its text now the way I do it is Attach to process --> search(w3wp.exe) and all the DNN based with directory or domain based is showing. here is a snap shot of it.


Now the problem is showing that the current break point will not hit.

I've refreshed plenty of times on IIS as well but it doesn't hit the debug mark.

I think you forgot to build the dll in debug mode before. Be carefull that the debug dll is copied in the root bin folder.

@StéphaneTETARD actually my source code is in D drive and the project is DNN8 folder is in C drive, I've clean and built the solution.

You have to copy the dll build in debug mode into the root bin folder of your DNN8 installation (drive C in your case).
